# Crystal report is not working properly in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, crystal-reports

I have developed a project in VS2005(C#) which contains two crystal reports, the project is working fine and crystal reports are running properly on my system. But when my friend tries to run the project on his system, then the projects runs well but when I am opening crystal reports I am getting the error shown in image below

[image: crystal report error in visual studio 2005]

We are not running packaged setup, its the whole project which we are running in framework getting this error.

Everything is installed correctly on my friends system, then why its giving this error, please tell me what we can do this to correct this error?

Comment: stop using crystal reports :)

Comment: is your friend a local administrator of his machine?

Comment: @lomaxx - we have our won laptops and we are the administrator of the system.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to reinstall CR runtime (like stated in message above) (disable all anitivrus software!). If this doesn't help (and CR won't run even at admin user account), then I would use Mark Russinovich Process Monitor to find out, what key or component can't be accessed/loaded. Of course you should look at windows events - maybe there are some meaningful messages there.